# Unique constraint on multiple columns based on start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, unique-constraint, data-integrity

I have this problem in which there is a link between two entities that could exist for a certain time, the relationship can be repeated multiple times during different dates.

How can I create a unique constraint in the database, based on the time of link?

Example, users owning cars:

```
UserID | CarID | DatePurchase | DateSell
-------+-------+--------------+---------
user1  | car1  | 2020-1-1     | 2020-6-1
user2  | car1  | 2020-6-1     | 2021-1-1
user1  | car1  | 2021-1-1     | NULL
```

In the above example, the car CAN NOT be owned by more than one user at the same time.

If I add a unique constraint on both `UserID` & `CarID` this will not allow the user to own the car more than once.

I also can't include the start date in the unique constraint as it will not fix the problem obviously if there were interlaps in the dates.

I don't want to leave such important rule to the business logic. I prefer to enforce such rules in the database, is there anyway I can add such a constraint at the database level?

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can combine the last two columns as a date range. Then just create a unique constraint with (carId, date-range). Isn't PostgreSQL great?

Comment: Is it possible to do that in Sql Server?

Comment: Ah... you changed the question. I don't think SQL Server can do that.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to mention the db engine.

Comment: One method would be to use a (**set-based**) trigger. Another would be to use a `VIEW` with a `JOIN` to your calendar table; then you could create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the `CarID` and Calender Date.